# objective-C and xcode: how to make text disappear when user touches TextView

Tags: objective-c, xcode, textview

I think I am supposed to use "clearsOnInsertion", but I'm not sure exactly how to do it. I just want the TextView to already say "Enter text here", and when the user clicks the TextView to type, it clears for them.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the .h file, subscribe to UITextViewDelegate, then in the .m file you can set the delegate of the textView to textView.delegate = self.  There is a delegate method called something like textViewDidBeginEditing or something like that.  In that method you can just say textView.text = @"";

EDIT:
The method is:

```
- (void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView
{
   //if you want it to only clear if the textView says "Enter text here" then do something like

   if ([textView.text isEqualToString:@"Enter text here"]) 
   { 
       textView.text = @"";
   }
}
```

Comment: Sounds good. However, can you please tell me how to 'subscribe' to UITextViewDelegate in my viewcontroller's header file? As far as I know I can only important a single superclass header, and have never heard of 'subscribing'

Comment: so lets say ur header file looks like MyViewController : UIViewController.  Make it look like MyViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate> EDIT: Putting <UITextFieldDelegate> next to your class decleration in your header file will tell the compiler that you will be implementing methods that are part of the UITextFieldDelegate protocol.

Comment: Thanks for the awesome answer, that really made sense and allowed me to find the documentation and read more about it. However, it doesn't work for me for some reason, and instead the console throws as error:   DataFile: file open error: /var/mobile/Library/Keyboard/dynamic-text.dat, (Permission denied)   Any ideas?

Comment: So that error does not seem to be involved with clearing a textview.  That specific file is used for caching user input in the keyboard for auto correct purposes.  Not sure why it would crash without the context of the code.  Just set some breakpoints in your code and step through the application to see where the crash is occurring.

Comment: Quick question... If i understand correctly, this method (   - (void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView   ) creates a pointer to the UITextView object. Does this mean that any TextView field I tap would trigger this method?

Comment: Yes, but you have to have the class set at that textViews delegate by doing, textView.delegate = self;